Is bit shift same as integer multiplication/divison in Python?
I read somewhere that they are different when the number is negative, but I did a quick test and it appears they are equivalent, at least in python?
for i in range(-1000, 1000):
    assert(i >> 1 == i // 2)
    assert(i << 1 == i * 2)


For Python's int type they are the same, in other languages where integer types are based on the usual CPU arithmetic, this may be different.
